# Interpreting the volume of parallelotope in $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am confused about the interpretation of the volume of parallelotope generated by the set of vectors $<a_1, \ldots, a_n>$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Squared Gram determinant gives the real value , which I don't know how to interpret properly. The point is, if we assume parallelotope stated above as $n$-th dimmensional object in $\mathbb{R^{2n}}$, then we'll receive some other value.

Can someone make this clear? Thanks!

Comment: Can you define this polytope using "set-builder notation"?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I suppose, that the parallelotope is $P(a_1, \ldots, a_n)= \sum \alpha_i\cdot a_i$, где $0 \leq \alpha_i \leq 1$ (the same as in real case), but it is not important in my question, because i'm looking for any geometrical interpretation of the real-value that is given by det of Gram matrix.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Note that the Gram determinant makes sense even if the number of vectors is $<n$. I therefore would look at this determinant if on ly two vectors $a$, $b\in{\mathbb C}^n$ are given, and see whether $\sqrt{G(a,b)}$ has some geometric meaning.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I will be thankful for any suggestions. Surely, it is correct for any set of independent vectors (in this case Gram determinant is not trivial). I would also like to notice that that we can assume n-th dimencional vectors over $\mathbb{C}$ as $2n$-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$. And there is some connection between determinant of Gram matrix in $\mathbb{C}^n$, and the deterinant of Gram matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, which is also very interesting